# PHP: what is the difference between session_name and cookie session name

Tags: php, session, cookies

In PHP sessions what's the difference between name set by `session_name()` and name in session cookies as in`setcookie(name,...)`.Do they have the same value ?

Comment: `setcookie` sends a regular cookie to the client. It has nothing to do with sessions.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois but Php manual and developers make multiple mention of Session cookies, are they not inter-related ?

Comment: PHP sessions use one regular cookie "session cookie" as uniqur identifier of a client. The session data is saved on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.The session name references the name of the session, which is used in cookies and URLs .
http://php.net/session_name